# CentOS colors in php-cli applications

Tags: centos, bash, terminal, bashrc, color

I'm managing a server with CentOS 6.5 x64 installed.

In my Ubuntu server, when I run `composer` or [Laravel](http://laravel.com)'s `artisan` php cli command, parameters are colorful.

[image: ubuntu terminal composer]

But this doesn't happen when I SSH into a CentOS server and run `composer` again.

[image: centos terminal ssh composer]

As you can see, the directories are colored as it should, but `php-cli` apps are not (Laravel's artisan command has same issue, too).

(This issue also occurs `nano` editor if that would help.)

Is there a way to "colorize" such commands in CentOS?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Chances are the `root` user isn't setup for color in `.bashrc` or other files. If you run `composer` as a different user on your CentOS server, does `composer` or `nano` give colorized output as you expect? There are [other things to check](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90013/how-do-i-enable-syntax-highlighting-in-nano) if the syntax coloring in `nano` isn't working.

Comment: @Bert sadly, when I login from another user, it's same.

Comment: Could you please run `echo $TERM` both on your ubuntu machine and your server and add the results to your question?

Comment: php-symphony requires php-posix to support color, for Centos 6.5 that should be in the php-process package `yum list php-process` or `yum provides php-posix`

Comment: @Brian that's it! Thanks, I can see colors in composer now colorful.